# How to keep relation of fields in a child entity

Tags: xml, solr, schema, parent-child

I have two tables customers and fees, related 1xn by `customer.id = fees.customerId`. fees has other two columns, `length` and `rate`. My solr config is:

schema.xml

```
<schema name="customers" version="1.5">
    <field name="_version_" type="long" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
    <field name="id" type="long" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
    <field name="customerName" type="string" indexed="false" stored="true"/>
    <field name="length" type="int" indexed="false" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
    <field name="rate" type="float" indexed="false" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>

    <uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>
    <fieldType name="long" class="solr.TrieLongField" precisionStep="0" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
    <fieldType name="int" class="solr.TrieIntField" precisionStep="0" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
    <fieldType name="float" class="solr.TrieFloatField" precisionStep="0" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
    <fieldType name="string" class="solr.StrField"/>
</schema>
```

solr-data-config.xml

```
<entity name="customer" query="SELECT * FROM customers">
    <field column="id" name="id"/>
    <field column="name" name="customerName"/>

    <entity name="fees" query="SELECT length, rate FROM fees WHERE id=${customer.id}">
       <field column="length" name="length"/>
        <field column="rate" name="rate"/>
    </entity>
</entity>
```

The problem is that because of Solr's flat schema, `length` and `rate` end up 'dissociated' from each other, as two lists. I want to have a single list of pairs, so a list `<length, rate>`. My current solution is to change the data config to

```
<entity name="fees" query="SELECT CONCAT(length, ';', rate) AS lengthRatePair FROM fees WHERE id=${customer.id}">
   <field column="lengthRatePair" name="lengthRatePair"/>
</entity>
```

And then at client side split the field by ;. But I think there must be a much more elegant solution.

What is the proper way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solr / Lucene will keep the sequence of values in a multivalued field as they were indexed, so even if they end up "disassociated", the first value in `length` will be related to the first value of `rate` - so you can use the same indices to look up values in both fields. This means that it's important to index the same count of entries in both fields.

Your other solution would work as well - regardless of what you choose, you'll have to do handle it in your query layer.

Doing it as child documents sounds like overkill, as that will complicate almost all other aspects without giving you anything in return for values that are just stored.

A third solution would be to just put a serialized json structure into a field to attach it to the document as well, but I prefer the first solution. We added a configuration setting to our query layer which tells the query layer which fields it should merge in a query result to a single entry, so that the display / view layer receives an object with a `{length: .., rate: ...}` hash as one of the properties.